# using PeriodIndex vs DateTimeIndex in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am working with some financial data that is organized as a df with a `MultiIndex` that contains the ticker and the date and a column that contains the return. I am wondering whether one should convert the index to a `PeriodIndex` instead of a `DateTimeIndex` since returns are really over a period rather than an instant in time. Beside the philosophical argument, what practical functionality does `PeriodIndex` provide that may be useful in this particular use case vs `DateTimeIndex`?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#converting-between-representations

Comment: i know how to convert hem, i'm just wondering when does one prove very useful vs the other?

Comment: Did you found anything about this?

Comment: i did not, if you have comments feel free

Comment: If your data is regularly sampled, one advantage of the period index is that it allows to directly compute time deltas (durations) between periods. By contrast, when using a date-time index, time deltas are expressed as days between time points and you have to do some rounding to get back lower frequencies like months or years.

Answer (score 2):

There are some functions available in DateTimeIndex (such as is_month_start, is_quarter_end) which are not available in PeriodIndex. I use PeriodIndex when is not possible to have the format I need with DateTimeIndex. For example if I need a monthly frequency in the format yyyy-mm, I use the PeriodIndex.

Example:
Assume that df has an index as

```
df.index
'2020-02-26 13:50:00', '2020-02-27 14:20:00',
'2020-02-28 11:10:00', '2020-02-29 13:50:00'],
 dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='peak_time', length=1025, freq=None)
```

The minimum monthly data can be obtained via the following code

```
dfg = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month]).min()
```

whose index is a MultiIndex

```
dfg.index
MultiIndex([(2017,  1),
             ...
            (2020,  1),
            (2020,  2)],
           names=['peak_time', 'peak_time'])
```

No I convert it to a PeriodIndex:

```
dfg["date"] = pd.PeriodIndex (dfg.index.map(lambda x: "{0}{1:02d}".format(*x)),freq="M")
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the PeriodIndex can be automatically displayed as the corresponding month, quarter and year in the downsampling.

```
import pandas as pd
# https://github.com/jiahe224/bug_report/blob/main/resample_test.csv
temp = pd.read_csv('resample_test.csv',dtype={'stockcode':str, 'A股代码':str})
temp['date'] = pd.to_datetime(temp['date'])
temp = temp.set_index(['date'])

result = temp['北向占自由流通比'].resample('Q',closed='left').first()
result
```

[image: DatetimeIndex]

```
result = temp['北向占自由流通比'].resample('Q',closed='left').first().to_period()
result
```

[image: PeriodIndex]

Off topic, there is a problem with resample that has not been fixed as of yet, the bug report at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/45869

Answer (score 0):

Behavior on partial periods.
`date_range` returns empty index. `period_range` returns index with `len` 1 when specifying `start` and `end` that do *not* cover a whole period.
(also, the timezone information is lost for periods of months).

- date_range:

  dates = pd.core.indexes.datetimes.date_range("2022-12-01 0:00:00+00:00", "2022-12-05 14:26:00+00:00", inclusive="both", freq="1M")
  dates
  DatetimeIndex([], dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', freq='M')
- period_range:

  periods = pd.core.indexes.period.period_range("2022-12-01 0:00:00+00:00", "2022-12-05 14:26:00+00:00", freq="1M")
  periods
  PeriodIndex(['2022-12'], dtype='period[M]')